# How can I install gephi?

Tags: software-installation

I'm failing to install Gephi properly on Ubuntu 12.04. I need to do some data analysis for a course using it.

Comment: For Trusty 14.04, try my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/531515/257249

Answer (score 7):

Install Sun Java via `Synaptic`, do a Quick Search Search for `sun java` and install the **jre** and **jdk.** Do not forget to run `update-alternatives –config java` and `update-alternatives –config javac`.

If you’re on the 8.10 version, please install Java manually from the Oracle website, because the distributed packages are obsolete.

Download gephi from here https://gephi.org/users/download/

Then After the download completes, unzip and untar the file in a directory.
Run it by executing `./bin/gephi` script file.

You can run the script file with

```
chmod +x /bin/gephi.sh
./bin/gephi.sh
```

Hope that helps .

[Source](https://gephi.org/users/install/)

Answer (score 4):

You can install the daily build from Launchpad. I've been using it for a while with no major issues.

First add the PPA to you software sources and update apt:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rockclimb/gephi-daily
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install gephi with:

```
sudo apt-get install gephi
```

Comment: Added repo, on update got the following error messages:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found

Comment: If you look on the PPA site, there is no build for quantal (as of 1/21/13)

Comment: Worked beautifully for me on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: Doesn't work for Xenial

Answer (score 3):

**For version 0.9.2 ; Working as of Jan 2020**

If you are using Debian 10 or Ubuntu 18 or later, `openjdk-8-jdk` is not available in your sources, do the following to install openjdk-8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

Now, ensure your java version is 8 and do the following:

```
curl -L -o gephi.tar.gz https://github.com/gephi/gephi/releases/download/v0.9.2/gephi-0.9.2-linux.tar.gz
tar xzvf gephi.tar.gz
```

Now, you can run it as with the command `bash $PWD/gephi-0.9.2/bin/gephi`

---

However, this is not an ideal solution and may not work in the future.
An alternative can be using a docker image like `atb00ker/docker-turnkey:gephi`. The  documentation for usage of this image can be found here:  https://github.com/atb00ker/docker-turnkey/tree/master/gephi

---

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly on Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

For people landing here somewhat after 2012, when the question was asked:
The answer by rɑːdʒɑ failed for me, but [this page here](https://installfights.blogspot.com/2018/11/how-to-run-gephi-in-ubuntu.html),  [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190102091950/https://installfights.blogspot.com/2018/11/how-to-run-gephi-in-ubuntu.html), has instructions to solve the problem. You need version <= 8 of JDK.

Comment: Please include a brief description how to solve the problem. The link you mentioned can be deleted or altered in the website.

Comment: I didn't want to steal credits from the author of that page. I would essentially copy his post.

Comment: I checked and the wayback archive has the page archived already.