# Difficulties installing Gephi on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, ppa

I have tried to open `Gephi` after download with `./gephi`from the `~/bin` file, which seems to work at first then it crashes. 
So I tried a different installation approach using : ([How can I install gephi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193287/how-can-i-install-gephi))

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rockclimb/gephi-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gephi
```

I got this after `sudo apt-get install gephi`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gephi : Depends: libgoogle-collections-java but it is not installable
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install libgoogle-collections-java` say?

Comment: `E: Package 'libgoogle-collections-java' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Well then that's your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package needs the package `libgoogle-collections-java` as a dependency, but you do not have a repository which provides this package. It seems that it was available in 10.04 and 12.04, but not in 14.04 for reasons that are unclear... You need to find this package in order to install Gephi.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's installing! I hope it won't crash this time. Thanks again

Comment: There is an answer on how to install gephi for 14.04 and fix the libgoogle-collections-jave problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/522715/problem-installing-gephi-after-installing-ppa-and-oracle-java-8/531515#531515